# How to refer to dataTable parent within the dataTable?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Consider a dummy case:

```
<h:form id="wrapperForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="rowsContainer">
        <h:dataTable id="rowsTable" value="#{bean.rows}" var="row" >
            <h:column>
                <h:commandButton value="Click me to update (#{component.parent.parent.parent.clientId})">
                    <f:ajax render=":#{component.parent.parent.parent.clientId}" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

On button click, the `id=rowsContainer` gets successfully updated as it should.

However, if I add `ui:repeat` there, it does not work anymore:

```
<h:form id="wrapperForm">
    <ui:repeat id="blocksRepeat" var="block" value="#{bean.blocks}">
        <h:panelGroup id="rowsWrapper">
            <h:dataTable id="rowsTable" value="#{block.rows}" var="row" >
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandButton value="Click me 2 update (#{component.parent.parent.parent.clientId})">
                        <f:ajax render=":#{component.parent.parent.parent.clientId}" />
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

Instead, this gets:

```
<f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':wrapperForm:blocksRepeat:0:rowsWrapper' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt363
```

However, that component is really there with that ID, so the EL should be ok. Somehow the `ui:repeat` breaks the case. Is it possibly trying to evaluate the EL before the actual loop?

How do you refer to the `rowsWrapper` element from within the dataTable?

Note: I recently asked about [odd dataTable naming within ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880993/why-doesnt-hdatatable-inside-uirepeat-get-correct-id), which [turned out to be a bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1830). This issue should not be related to that, however, as I am wrapping the dataTable within a panelGroup as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424757/ajax-render-attribute-dont-work-in-a-hdatatable-in-jsf2).

Comment: `ui:repeat` again ~sic. It would be nice if the JSF guys introduced a fullworthy `UIData` component which is similar to good ol' Tomahawk's `t:dataList` which allows output markup control as `<ul>`, `<ol>` or nothing.

Comment: But in this case the clientIDs that the dataTables get, really are unique. Also, I don't even try to refer directly to the dataTables here, but to their panelGroup wrappers (so the reference should not cause an issue). I would have thought that makes a difference, but guess it still causes some issues then?

Comment: No, the problem is that `ui:repeat` isn't a fullworthy `UIData` component and behaves differently as oppsed to e.g. `HtmlDataTable`. If you replace `ui:repeat` by `h:dataTable` it will work (but the final HTML is is ugly, yes).

Comment: You are right, I had a similar case when replacing the `ui:repeat` with `h:dataTable` really solved the situation (believe it does so in this case as well). However, in some cases simply updating to Mojarra 2.0.3 helped, I actually opened up a question that should summarize the whole hassle around ui:repeat (not to duplicate information but to help other desperate souls find the cause when in the same situation). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890862/jsf-mojarra-2-0-2-uirepeat-is-totally-broken-when-updating-via-ajax/3890890 It seems they fixed at least something for Mojarra 2.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two things going wrong:

**1) ui:repeat is broken**

As answered by BalusC in the comments of the question, the first issue occurs (once again) due to [a bug in Mojarra](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1830). It seems `ui:repeat` is so broken even the wrapper container holding the `h:dataTable` does not help. For more details, see question "[Why doesn't h:dataTable inside ui:repeat get correct ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880993/why-doesnt-hdatatable-inside-uirepeat-get-correct-id)" and the comments of this question.

As BalusC suggests, a workaround is to use h:dataTable instead of `ui:repeat`. It will provide unconvenient (`<table>`) HTML but works. This removes some odd issues when adding and removing rows to/from the inner iteration.

Note: some issues regarding `ui:repeat` seem to be fixed in Mojarra 2.0.3 but not all.

**2) The references just fail**

Even with `h:dataTable` workaround, the reference to the inner `h:dataTable` from the button inside it fails. As there is no `ui:repeat` in use, this must be datatable's internal issue. I don't see any solution at the moment, so I [filed a ticket for this behavior as well](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1834).